# エラー　画像を自動でしきい値を決めて2値化したい。大津のアルゴリズム

Tags: python, opencv, 画像, anaconda

AnacondaでOpenCVを学習しております。指定画像を2値化して表示をしたいのですが、エラーが返されます。
使用環境: Anaconda3(Python 2.7.13), Windows 7, OpenCV 3.2.0

試みた実行したのは下記[threshold.py]です。

```
# coding: UTF-8
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('01.png', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, th_Otsu = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imshow('01_Otsu.png', th_Otsu)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

下記　実行時のエラーです。

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1) in cv::threshold, file C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp, line 1356
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3/threshold.py", line 7, in <module>
    ret, th_Otsu = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1356: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::threshold
```

---

[+ cv2.THRESH_OTSU]を消して実行すれば正常に表示できるのですが、しきい値を自動で決めたいのでcv2.THRESH_OTSUが使いたいです。OTSUが使えない実行環境なのでしょうか？
調べてみたのですが明確な答えがわかりませんでした。
ご助言を頂ければ助かります、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> img = cv2.imread('01.png', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> ```

`cv2.imread`メソッドへの第二引数が誤っています。画像ファイルをグレイスケールとして読み込む場合は、定数`cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`または値`0`を指定してください。（`cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`は値`6`です）

```
 img = cv2.imread('01.png', 0)
```

Comment: yohjpさん回答ありがとうございます。imreadの使い方に注意が必要でした。無事に解決できました。